# index of a group and element of a center order are co-prime

Tags: group-theory

This is a weird question:

> Let $G$ be a group and $H$ its subgroup of index 5. $a \in Z(G)$ and $ord(a)=3$. Prove that $a\in H$.

So my idea was to look at $\langle aH\rangle$, we know that $H \le \langle aH\rangle$  and that:

$5=[G:H] = [G: \langle aH\rangle]\cdot [\langle aH\rangle:H]$

therefore since 5 is a prime we have the two situations:

i) $[G:\langle aH\rangle]=5$ and $[\langle aH\rangle:H]=1$ - in which $H=\langle aH\rangle$ thus $a\in H$

ii) $[G:\langle aH\rangle]=1$ and $[\langle aH\rangle:H]=5$ - in which we get $G=\langle aH\rangle$ but I fail to see a contradition here.

Will appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, you are very close. You already know that $[\langle aH\rangle : H] \mid 5$.

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $a \notin H$. Then the elements of $\langle aH\rangle$ are of the form $a^kh$ for $h\in H$. Since the order of $a$ is $3$, this means that the distinct cosets are $\{H, aH, a^2H\}$, so that $[\langle aH\rangle : H] = 3$, which contradicts the fact that $[\langle aH\rangle : H] \mid 5$.

Answer (score 0):

In the second case, where $a\notin H$, $\langle aH\rangle$ is a direct product of $H$ and $\langle a\rangle$, the cyclic group generated by $a$. This wouldn't be true in general, but it is true here because $a$ is in the center of $G$. Therefore, $[aH:H]=\operatorname{ord}(a)=3$, giving us a contradiction.